# Image Magick Issue:no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-1S39vaNx'

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, imagemagick, rmagick, imagemagick-convert

Am using Image magick in my project(Ubuntu.12).I successfully installed imagemagick from source itself.while running the project am getting the following error

```
    no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-1S39vaNx'
 @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/566
```

How this error can be rectified?

Comment: Could you add relevant lines of Ruby code where this error occurs? Often this error is associated with mis-labelled file extensions, zero-byte files, files that are not images. So it is worth verifying the type of file independently, too.